# Apple Push Notification Service not work in production

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, push-notification

Gateway Timeout

The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.

Get this response in production,but working with sandbox like charm,please help me if any one have idea.

Comment: Do you have changed the server link? Do you have the SSL port open?

Comment: Are you using the correct url and are you using the prod certificate?

Comment: Yes i am change url this url "ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195" for production and my certificate is for production.

Comment: Push notification is work if i am run php file from my mac terminal.But problem is with my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solve,because the issue is from my hosting server, in my hosting server port 2195 is close so server can not connect to apple server.thanks kerberos